# Listing pages which uses specific template

Tags: pages, templates, list

I have created a template named `product.php` with the following header:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Product Page
*/
```

How can I list, in a sidebar, every page that uses the "Product Page" template?

I have tried reading the `wp_list_pages()` function documentation, but it only seemed possible to list filtering by `post_type`, not by template used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with a [`WP_Query` `meta_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters). The page template filename is stored in post meta under the key `_wp_page_template`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'value' => 'product.php'
        )
    )
);
$the_pages = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $the_pages->have_posts() ){
    while( $the_pages->have_posts() ){
        $the_pages->the_post();
        the_title();
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: You beat me by 47 seconds!

Comment: ... and someone beat us by a couple of years ;-)

Answer (score 2):

the page template is setted via a meta field with the key `'_wp_page_template'`. The value for this meta field is the **php full file name** of the template file, something like

'`page-products.php'`

so you can create a custom function to easyly get the page with a specific template using meta_key and meta_value param off `get_pages` (or using a `WP_Query` with `'meta_query'` argument):

```
get_pages_by_template( $template = '', $args = array() ) {
  if ( empty($template) ) return false;
  if ( strpos($template, '.php') !== (strlen($template) - 4) )  $template .= '.php';
  $args['meta_key'] = '_wp_page_template';
  $args['meta_value'] = $template;
  return get_pages($args);
}
```

This function accepts as first (mandatory) argument the template and as second (optional) argument all the arguments of [get_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages).

the template can passed with or without '.php' extension:

```
$pages = get_pages_by_template('page-products');
```

or

```
$pages = get_pages_by_template('page-products.php');
```

After that, you can use the page retrieved as you want: loop throu them and output some markup, create a custom widget that make use of the function, and so on...